# parent, view, and id Parameteris never used could be renamed to_ (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am doing a lisview in andadroid studio with kotlin, but when I create the setOnItemClickListene, it shows me that parent, view, and id Parameteris never used could be renamed to_, I don't understand why I get this warning in my code.
What should I do to remove this warning?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val listapaises = arrayOf(
            "Colombia", "Argentina",
            "Ecuador", "Venezuela",
            "Brasil", "Paraguay", "Uruguay",
            "Bolivia", "Peru", "Chile"
        )
        val habitantes = arrayOf(
            40_000_000, 17_000_000,
            6_500_000, 10_000_000,
            30_000_000, 14_000_000,
            183_000_000, 44_000_000,
            31_000_000, 3_500_000
        )
        val adaptador1 =
            ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listapaises)
        lv_lista.adapter = adaptador1

        lv_lista.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            tv_resultado.text = ("${habitantes[position]}")
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below code:

```
lv_lista.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
    tv_resultado.text = ("${habitantes[position]}")
}
```

Now, the warning you see is because of three lambda parameters which are unused in this case - `parent`, `view` and `id`.

What it wants you to do is to replace these three unused parameters with `_`. This will remove the unused parameter warnings and it will also prevent `IllegalArgumentException` in the case that the parameter was null and was marked non-null.

The [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#underscore-for-unused-variables-since-11) states that parameters can be replaced with `_` when not in use. So, what you have to do is change your code as:

```
lv_lista.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _->
    tv_resultado.text = ("${habitantes[position]}")
}
```

In case you want to keep them for future references, you can use `@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")` to suppress the warning.